# how to prevent parsing webservice response string

Tags: web-services, xml-parsing, webservice-client

how can I prevent string argument from beeing parsed as xml ?

```
<s:element name="MyResponse">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element type="s:string" name="xmlResultWithStringType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"  />       
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

in log I have a correct answer -

```
Hello xmlStart <foo>in foo<bar>in bar</bar> end foo</foo> xmlEnd
```

full log :

```
    ---[HTTP request - http://localhost:8080/mockXXX]---
Accept: application/soap+xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8;action="http://xxx"
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.7-b01  svn-revision#13316
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><S:Body><MyRequest xmlns="http://fff"><xmlRequest>req do webserwisu</xmlRequest></MyRequest></S:Body></S:Envelope>--------------------

---[HTTP response - http://localhost:8080/mockXXX - 200]---
null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
Server: Jetty(6.1.x)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:fff="http://fff">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <fff:MyResponse>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <fff:XmlResultWithStringType>Hello xmlStart <foo>in foo<bar>in bar</bar> end foo</foo> xmlEnd</fff:XmlResultWithStringType>
      </fff:MyResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>--------------------
```

but webservice call returns **only** 
**xmlEnd2** 
whole beginning is lost, the content of XmlResultWithStringType is parsed by xml parser,
but it should not, 
how can I prevent it from beeing parsed  ?
I use jax-ws-RI implementation,

Answer (score 0):

it should be but into CDATA section

```
<![CDATA[ any xml possible here, it won't be treated as xml but as string ]]>
```

otherwise, without CDATA, it is treated as xml not as string.